# Is there some way to find the intersect in multiple file names between multiple CSV headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop through all CSV files in a folder and find all header names that are in all files.  I am thinking the code would start like this...it needs treatment and enhancement, for sure.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

csvs = glob.glob('C:\\my_path\' + '*.csv')

master_set = set()

for file in csvs:
    this_df = pd.read_csv(file)
    cols = set(this_df.columns)
    master_set = master_set.intersection(cols)

print(master_set)
```

This is just looping through files in a folder, obviously.  What I want to do is compare all CSV headers in one folder, and check for the matches (intersection) of all headers, and print that result.  Does it make sense?  I hope so.  I will need to do a UNION of all these files at some point.  I am trying to determine the best way to get all common headers together.  This is the lowest common denominator of the whole data series.

So, if I have 4 files with this schema:

```
colA colB colC colD colE
```

And, I have one file with this schema:

```
colA colC colE colX colX
```

Then, this is want I to see:

```
colA colC colE
```

Comment: You should try to write something yourself that solves the problem and ask about specific issues with it - the question as it currently stands is too broad and amounts to asking people here to solve the problem for you. You need to: open the files you found, read the headers, collect the headers, and figure out a way to get the intersection (not the union) of the resulting sets. All those are fairly trivial tasks, but feel free to come ask about any of them if you have trouble implementing them. (by the way, the answer to your question is "yes, there is")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking to:

1. Identify the .csv files
2. Grab the headers
3. Intersect the headers

The answer above will work for parts 2 and 3. For part 1, I would recommend something like the following to grab paths to all of the relevant files. Unless you have a fancier pattern to match, good old `glob` is best.

```py
import glob

csvs = glob.glob('PATH_TO_CSV_DIR' + '*.csv')
```

I would then create a master set against which you can compare the header of each new .csv:

```py
import pandas as pd

master_set = set()

for file in csvs:
    this_df = pd.read_csv(file)
    cols = set(this_df.columns)
    master_set = master_set.intersection(cols)
```

Something like that should append all the unique headers.

Comment: This looks very promising, but I'm not getting any results at all.  I'm going to update my original post, based on your suggestions, and hopefully someone will come through with a working solution.

Comment: This was sort of a pseudo code so that you can get a gist for what the solution might look like. There are nuances that will need to be worked out on your end, of course. Generally if you ask the question more thoroughly, the quality and usefulness of the answers will improve. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it but would require you to loop in a loop on list of files and store the results. As far as a sample, here is the code.

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("File1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("File2.csv")
setA = set(df1.columns)
setB = set(df2.columns)
common = setA.intersection(setB)
```

Comment: Pandas also has a index intersection function. df.columns.intersection(df.columns) . Also it has a sort parameter which if set to false retains the original order

Comment: @ Pravan...this is almost exactly what I want.  But, how can the code be changed to read through all CSV files in a folder and do the same.  So, I may have 100+ files that I need to check.  I don't want to hard-code the file names.  I want the code to read through the files dynamically and find the intersection of all field names.  How can that be done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in the following way. The code works for any number of CSV files.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob

path = r'PATH_TO_CSV_DIR' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv('PATH_TO_CSV_DIR/c15.csv') # to initialize the master_set
master_set = set(df1.columns)

for file in all_files:
    this_df = pd.read_csv(file)
    cols = set(this_df.columns)
    master_set = master_set.intersection(cols)

w = csv.writer(open("CommonColumns.csv","w")) #it gives a CSV file of common header. The common header can be used later for other operations. 
w.writerow(master_set)
print(master_set)
```